# Trying to Auto delete only auto saved files

Tags: raspberrypi

I am trying to implement Auto delete in raspberry pi. I already created auto logging. Now I want to delete only auto logged files if it is 6 days older.
On this page I found this command

find '/home/securityuser*' -mtime +6 -type f -delete

I am using it as
find /home/pi/${LOGFILE_NAME}${LOGFILE_DATE}*random*${RANDOM} -type f
-mtime +6 -delete

This is giving me an error:
find: `/home/pi/_random_10375': No such file or directory